# Plot of $\int^x_0 e^{-t^2} dt$

Tags: integration, graphing-functions

I know that the function is strictly monotone, since $f'(x)$ is always positive, and it is convex in $]-\infty, 0]$ and concave in $]0, +\infty[$ because if its second derivative.

However, I am also provided with the information that

$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-t^2} dt = \sqrt{\pi}$

but I don't know how to use this information.

I'm sure it somehow shows that it converges to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, but how do I prove that?

Comment: You can deduce that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt = \sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: Why not go to WolframAlpha if you simply want the plot?

Comment: @Vim I know the plot, I want to know how to deduce it by myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional information tells you that $y=\pm\sqrt\pi/2$ are horizontal asymptotes.